# QGis / Scale & scalebar wrong

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale, qgis-2.10, scale-bar

First, I would like to apologize for the mistakes. My English is not very good. I read a lot but I don´t find the answer.
I'm trying to put a scalebar in a very simple map but the measurement is not correct. I'm going to describe the process (spanis version 2.10.1):

1) I open QGis -> project -> properties

2) General -> measurement tool WGS84 (SRC transformation connected)

3)SRC on the fly activated (SRC 3857 and also tried with 4326 similar results)

4) New Shapefile -> line shapefile -> I create a line of 10.000 m length (measured with the qgis measurement tool)

5) Print composer -> new map -> escale ej 1:10.000 -> add scale bar.

6) Export to PDF

7)I print the map (from PDF to printer with pdf not scaled) and the scale with the scalebar and is not correct

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your scale bars will be useless with WGS84 EPSG 4326, or Web Mercator EPSG 3857. The scale will depend on how high up on the canvas you measure. If you want something meaningful use a UTM projection or some other Equal Area.